# What is the tool to send file to SPIFSS on ESP8266/32?

Tags: esp8266, spi, esp32

Is there good tools (IDE, CLI or IDE addon) to send file via USB port to SPIFSS internal espressif ESP hardware SoC ?

Comment: Have you read the manual? http://esp8266.github.io/Arduino/versions/2.0.0/doc/filesystem.html

Comment: yes, but it's a LOT faster to load it over wifi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [mkspiffs](https://github.com/igrr/mkspiffs) tool creates bin from file system data (or extracts data from bin).

SPIFFS bin is uploaded with esptool over USB or with espota over WiFi. It can be uploaded with the sketch binary in one command.

Example:

```
esptool.py -p /dev/ttyUSB0 write_flash 0x0 sketch.bin 0x300000 spiffs.bin
```

[The IDE plugin](https://github.com/esp8266/arduino-esp8266fs-plugin/blob/master/README.md) adds SPIFFS upload to Arduino IDE Tools menu.